# Sort a Dataset[String] in Scala

Tags: scala, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I have `dsString: Dataset[(String,Long)]` (No DataFrame or Dataset[Row]) and I'm trying to order by Long `.orderBy(_._2)`

My problem is that `.orderBy()` and `.sort()` only accept columns, and I can only use `.sortBy` with RDDs.

DataFrame solution

```
dsString.toDF("a", "b")
  .groupBy("b")
```

RDD solution:

```
 dsString.toJavaRDD
    .sortBy(_._2)
```

How could `Dataset[(String,Long)]` do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Dataset also can be applied orderBy. For example,

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  c|  3|
|  b|  5|
|  a|  4|
+---+---+
```

this is my Dataset and

```
df2.orderBy(col("_1").desc).show
df2.orderBy(col("_2").asc).show
```

give the results as follows:

```
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  c|  3|
|  b|  5|
|  a|  4|
+---+---+


+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  c|  3|
|  a|  4|
|  b|  5|
+---+---+
```